# Limit the number of pending suggested edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

Recently, I have noticed several users below the 2000 rep threshold going on an retagging spree in the suggested edit queue.

Can we limit the number of pending suggested edits to 5 or 10 to discourage such batch edits? After all suggesting major retagging on meta often makes more sense than binding reviewer capacities in large scale.

Comment: Of course, no-brainer.  But there is no "we", only SE staff can get that ball rolling.  You'll have to use the [feature-request] tag.  Don't get your hopes up and consider that this might be just another temporary hat-problem.

Comment: I do think it would be a good idea regardless of hats. If a tag is getting burninated or cleaned up I think it's better handled by users with edit privileges to keep the number of trivial edits in the review queue down.

Comment: Been suggested on MSE previously: [Rate limit suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits), plus a few other related ones as well.

Comment: @psubsee2003, I see, thanks for catching that.

Comment: @cel the issue probably needs new attention, so good you brought it up.  I think it is time for a bounty......

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've bountied it again, because another editor is on a spree right now. And too many reviewers are robo-approving it. Limiting the editing rate seems the only way to contain the damage.

Comment: Since this got tagged [tag:status-completed] might we know what the limit is?

Comment: [The limit is 5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/153008), @ivarni.